Ldap filter not working for filtering out OU
I am looking to filter out an OU. For example, I would like to filter out OU=Designers
OU=Designers,OU=Employees,DC=company,DC=com
I am using this ldap filter,
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(distinguishedName=CN=*,OU=Designers,OU=Employees,DC=company,DC=com)))
This is not working. Is there something I am missing here?
I tried an ldap filter but it is not working. I am looking to filter out an OU. Used this as reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax

How about:
(&(objectClass=person)(!(OU=Designers)))

That did not work.

LDAP as a protocol does not support "wildcards" on distinguishedNames.
CN=*,OU=Designers,OU=Employees,DC=company,DC=com

And filters similer to
(&(objectClass=person)(!(OU=Designers)))

Will only work IF "OU=Designers" is added to the person entity's themselves.
And unfortunately, Microsoft does not support Extensible Match, you could use do it like:
(&(objectClass=person)(!(ou:dn:=Designers)))


I tried this (&(objectClass=person)(!(ou:dn:=Designers)))
That did not work either.

Are you using Microsoft Active Directory?

(&(objectClass=User)(objectcategory=person)(!(|(msDS-parentdistname=OU=Designers,OU=Employees,DC=company,DC=com))))
this worked.
